# Get the rownumber a variable reached the max value in a data.frame column R

Tags: r, dataframe

i need some help to find the row number that have the max value for each column

```
Data = data.frame(  
                    V1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9),
                    v2 = c(0.1, 0.12, 0.41, 0.72, 0.91),
                    v3 = c(0.03, 0.13, 0.92, 0.50, 0.90))
```

Desired result: (Time of max value)

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  5  5  3
```

I tried this, but without sucess:

```
lapply(Data, function(x) (which(max(x))))
```

Comment: Your attempt would work if you modified to `function(x) which(x == max(x))`. (But of course the special-purpose `which.max` is faster.)

Comment: `lapply(Data, which.max)`, `summarise_all(Data, which.max)`, `map_dbl(Data, which.max)`, `sapply(Dat, which.max)` etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using `dplyr::across`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~which.max(.x)))

  V1 v2 v3
1  5  5  3
```

Or using `sapply`,

```
sapply(Data, function(x) which.max(x))

V1 v2 v3 
 5  5  3
```

Comment: A tip, you don't need a function: `sapply(Data, which.max)`

Comment: I realised using . instead of .x in `~which.max(.x)` gives the same result. Could you briefly explain the usage of .x?

Comment: @Desmond `.` in `dplyr` means the data in pipe itself. In this case, there's no matter of `.` and `.x`.

Comment: `Data %>% summarise(across(everything(), which.max))`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`max.col`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/maxCol) and [`t`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/t) from **base R**:

```
max.col(t(Data))
```

Output:

```
[1] 5 5 3
```

The steps of this:

1. First transpose the data:

   ```
   > t(Data)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
   V1 0.10 0.20 0.40 0.70 0.90
   v2 0.10 0.12 0.41 0.72 0.91
   v3 0.03 0.13 0.92 0.50 0.90
   ```
2. Then get the column with the maximum value for each row:

   ```
   > max.col(t(Data))
   [1] 5 5 3
   >
   ```

---

Or `apply`:

```
apply(Data, 1, which.max)
```